# C / Real Time initialize memory with different type of datas

Tags: c, arrays, memory, hex, real-time

I'm facing an issue :

Today i want declare 300 bytes and initialize them with different datas

for example :

```
unsigned short memory[] = { 

0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, "X6", "M1", 1, 150 , 6, .....

}
```

I want to do that because i want that my data to be initialize on memory as this :
Value of X and 6 on the same 2 Bytes. if i do 'X', '6' i'll have :
0x0058 and 0x0006 instead of 0x5806..

Can you please light my mind ?
I'm a begginer in real time development.

Thanx for your times.

Naqued

Comment: `unsigned short memory[] = {

0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, ((unsigned short)('X')<<8) | ((unsigned short)(6)), ((unsigned short)('M')<<8) | ((unsigned short)(1)),1, 150 , 6

};`

Answer (score 2):

`"X6"` is a string that consists of 3 bytes. I don't know what your compiler does with it (complain?).

To create an unsigned short initializer with characters, use `'XX'` for example, which results in `0x5858`. To use values of nibbles that are not characters you can include an escaped value in the character constant.

`'X\x06'` would give you `0x5806`. Note how the second byte uses a hexadecimal escape character within the character constant, written as a  backslash (start of escape), followed by 'x' (the base of the number that follows), followed by the byte value 06. Depending on your architecture, you may need to write it as `'\x06X'`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to declare a 2-byte item array, but initialize some elements byte by bytes.

If you want to do that following your example syntax, you could do it with binary operations :

```
'X' << 8 | 6
```

Here you are starting with the binary value of char 'X', offsetting it by 8 bits left, thus occupying the leftmost byte of the 2-byte unsigned short. Then you are doing a binary OR with what you want on the right byte to insert it.

So in your case it would be :

```
unsigned short memory[] = {
    0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 'X' << 8 | 6, 'M' << 8 | 1, 1, 150 , 6, .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your respons.

I found an other way to do it :

```
{ 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, (('X' << 8) + '6') }
```

Here i'm offsetting X on 8bits left and simply add the '6' carac by + .

it do the right things too.
i understand better how work byte offset now.

Thanks to all